# Facing problems with Facebook SDK

Tags: android, facebook

I have learned the basics of android and now i wish to include the facebook sdk in my project.This is the link where i was trying to learn initially https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/ but the problem is ,when i import the projects that i downloaded and try to run them ,the compiler gives an error .
i need someone's help to guide me through ! I really need to do this

in this guide on developers.facebook.com i have issues on this particular line which is

"Secondly, locate the adb tool in the platform-tools directory of your main Android SDK. On OS X, you will have chosen this location when you unzipped the Android SDK. On Windows, the SDK is installed into your home directory, under AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk

Assuming you've placed the Facebook SDK in your home directory, you use adb to install the APK to the running emulator in OS X like this:

./adb install ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk

And on Windows, like this:

adb install %HOMEPATH%\facebook-android-sdk-3.5\bin\FBAndroid-3.5.apk

Once complete, check the apps screen of the emulator to check that the app has been installed correctly. If you need to force the upgrade of this app from a previous version, add the -r flag, like this on OS X:

./adb install -r ~/facebook-android-sdk-3.5/bin/FBAndroid-3.5.apk

You should now see the Facebook app in the emulator's app list or home screen."

NEED HELP !

Answer (score 0):

This is a tutorial for installing Facebook app on your emulator. Facebook SDK have a web fallback, so it will work even without installing it on the emulator.

Alternatively you can debug your application on real device that Facebook does installed on it and see the differences.

Comment: yes i am having problems in installing .apk file on my emulator

Comment: when i exucute the adb install homepath\filename.apk it gives an error saying it's not file

Comment: i have two .adb files , one in 
D:\junaid\android sdk\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20131030\sdk\platform-tools
one in
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools
when i was executing from the first folder it was giving the error ""its not a file""
when i executed it from the second folder it says 
""adb server is out of date.killing 
*deamon started successfully "
please guys need your help ,i really wanna do this

Comment: facebook app installed on my emulator despite the error,although my projects are showing a question mark (red) ,only those which i imported from the samples in the facebook sdk ,my java compiler shows 1.6 compliance level , need help ?